# Integrate from DataContract to IXmlSerializable using NetDataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, netdatacontractserializer

I have some data that is persisted in a database. The serialized content was originally written using the default `NetDataContractSerializer` with a `DataContract` attribute on the classes.
Now I want to move to using classes that implement `IXmlSerializable` to have more control over the serialized content and make it leaner and faster.
How will I be able to read the current content as well as store future content in the new way.
I have looked into `ISurrogateSelector`, but it doesn't seem to do the trick as the `ISerializationSurrogate` interface only supports getting and setting object data as the `ISerializable` interface, but no way to specify `ReadXml` and `WriteXml` as in `IXmlSerializable` interface. As I am reading in the stream, I don't have any information about the format other than the stream itself.
The deserialization must produce the same class instance regardless of the original serialization method.
I need to make a solution that uses .NET Framework 4.6